# Woocommerce action на перемещение order в корзину

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, action

Мне необходимо получить order_id, когда его перемещают в корзину(статус: move to trash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте действие `wp_trash_post`:

```
add_action( 'wp_trash_post', 'trash_post_action' ), 5, 1 );
function trash_post_action( $id ) {
    if ( ! $id ) {
        return;
    }

    $post_type = get_post_type( $id );

    // If this is an order, do something
    if ( in_array( $post_type, wc_get_order_types( 'order-count' ) ) ) {
        // process $id
    }
}
```

Приоритет установлен в 5, чтобы этот код сработал раньше стандартного в WooCommerce.

Comment: Спасибо большое, а то не мог найти action